# Horizontal issue on Chrome pure CSS parallax

Tags: html, css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/11ec63xj/1/

Try to open above example in mobile, or in the result of jsfildle, click and drag to the right. In mobile also, when you swipe to the right, it will break.

```
.parallax {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I also tried  `user-scalable=no` but the problem is still there.

Comment: have u tried overflow-x on body?

Comment: @jamieeason it's there as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, but now with solution.. kind off
Problem is with your

```
  .parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .parallax__layer--deep {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

in particular **scale()** make your elements wider so it goes beyond viewport

overflow: hidden does not work with mobile especially when you use user-scrollable: no/0

mobile devices skip or overflow or this commant in meta viewport (have no idea why)

Eighter way you have 3 solutions for me:

- rebuild website and do effect without scale() and will for just perfect
- Disable scroll but unfortunately both vertical and horizontal so you
  cant move

  ```
      <script>
          document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
      </script>
  ```
- You can use hammer or touchswipe to determine which axis to disable

http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/

In this case it would be like that 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/kLp8n9z9/)

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

Comment: I solved it, I simply wrap the .parallax with a wrap saying overflow hidden it solved everything.

Comment: I'm glad you did, so my anwser maybe will help someone alse with other project